# File upload in spring webflux - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to upload a file using Spring Webflux, but I'm getting the error `Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/documents")
class MyController(val myService: MyService) {

    @PostMapping
    fun create(@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile): Mono<ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>> {
        return myService.create()
    }
}
```

I've also tried replacing `@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile` with `ServerRequeset`, but I get the error:

> "Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest' on public reactor.core.publisher.Mono>> co.example.controllers.MyController.create(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest)"

Comment: if it's a multipart request, `@RequestPart` should be used here. Also, do you have the Synchronoss NIO Multipart library as a dependency?

Comment: Oooh the handler method is now being hit when I'm using `@RequestPart` :) Now it just says the format pdf is not supported. I don't have an explicit nio multipart depency declared in `build.gradle`

Comment: Where i am added the @RequestPart ? Can you please post an answer or something ?

Comment: @Clement how did you resolved your issue with pdf not supported :)

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS apologies for the oversight of not doing so earlier. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to `FilePart` from `MultipartFile` is what ended up working for me :)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/uploads")
class UploadsController(val exampleService: ExampleService) {

    @PostMapping(consumes = ["multipart/form-data"])
    fun create(@RequestPart("file") filePart: FilePart) = exampleService.save(filePart)

}
```

Comment: Clement, what really really worked for me is the answer here, i asked a question here  https://stackoverflow.com/q/55632633/4970079

Comment: Adding just @RequestPart resolves the first error and leads to another one which is no file is supported,. txt,. pdf whatever.... did you resolved that just by adding  this annotation?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS it wasn't just about the annotation. It was also the class of the request part being of class `FilePart` instead of `MultipartFile` :)