# Spring WebFlux - Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-web

I am using `spring-webflux` and want to upload files .... everything works great with just `spring-web` but when it comes to `webflux` i have not a clue what's wrong .

Be careful in the difference ... i am using :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So let's say we have the below `@RestController` , for `Spring Web` it works like charm:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
public Response uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

}
```

Now trying the same with `Spring-webflux` produces the below error :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-11T13:31:01.705+0000",
    "path": "/upload",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"
}
```

---

I found from a [random](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHGNz.png) stackoverflow question that i have to use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` but now i am getting the below error and i don't have a clue why this happens ?

The error is the below :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-11T12:27:59.687+0000",
    "path": "/uploadFile",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"
}
```

Even with `.txt` files is producing the same error :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-11T12:27:59.687+0000",
    "path": "/uploadFile",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"
}
```

Below is the **Postman Configuratio**n which is pretty straight forward , i am just calling with a post request and modified only the body as shown in the picture .

[image]

By the way i have added the needed properties on application.properties too :)

```
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is http multipart request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)

Comment: Well if you look a at the answer you will see that the content-type for a multipart can't be application/xml. So there is that.

Comment: @JEY I get the same error for text/plain or whatever file i add sir :)

Comment: I think there is a problem with your request cause I created a sample project https://gist.github.com/Julien-Eyraud/4a9384e11372004d0218a9e8a961108a and it just work

Comment: @JEY I followed this tutorial :) https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/ but he is using `spring-web` we are using `spring-webflux` and there is all the problem . I used the same request for `spring-web` and it works :'( i am troubleshouting with it all day :(

Comment: @JEY can you show me how you called it from postman or something :) ? I will be very happy to accept your answer .

Comment: @JEY using your service with a `.txt` file i get the below : `Content type 'text/plain' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`

Comment: https://ibb.co/q9KppgY don't know if it's helping. But I can see that you set a header. I didn't

Comment: Completely modified the question with new image so you can see what exactly happens . Please see that i am using `spring-webflux`

Comment: @JEY Somebody posted an amazing answer .... as you can see it was complicated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart) sais :

> The DefaultServerWebExchange uses the configured `HttpMessageReader<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>` to parse multipart/form-data content into a MultiValueMap.
>
> To parse multipart data in streaming fashion, you can use the Flux returned from an HttpMessageReader instead.

With few words you need to do something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> uploadFile(@RequestBody Flux<Part> parts) {
    //...
    }
```

Look at this [example](https://github.com/entzik/reactive-spring-boot-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thekirschners/springbootsamples/reactiveupload/ReactiveUploadResource.java)

Comment: Thank you Nikolay , i am very new to this ... how i can get the file from inside the parts :) ?

Comment: Look at [this example](https://github.com/entzik/reactive-spring-boot-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thekirschners/springbootsamples/reactiveupload/ReactiveUploadResource.java)

Comment: You already learned that switching from web to webflux is more than changeing the artifactId ;)

Comment: Nikolay i have a question ? Will this work okay for 1 GB files or the Service will crash ?

Comment: Webflux works great for uploading/downloading large files. There were [some issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21879) for streaming very large files few months ago but I think it is fixed now. It all depends on how is used.